# SQL query not working in hibernate : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: hibernate

here is my query which i am running using hiberante:

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT {User.*}," +
                           "{Address.*}  from T_USER_DETAILS2 US,T_ADDRESS_DETAILS AD where US.ADDRESS_ID = AD.ADDRESS_ID" +
                           " AND US.USER_FIRSTNAME = :firstname";

    SQLQuery sql =  session.createSQLQuery(sqlStr).addEntity("User",User.class).addEntity("Address",Address.class);
    sql.setParameter("firstname", firstname);

    System.out.println("Query created, now executing the query in the database");

    List<Object[]> list = sql.list();
```

here is the query generated by hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ SELECT
        User.USER_ID as USER1_1_0_,
        User.ADDRESS_ID as ADDRESS9_1_0_,
        User.USER_AGE as USER2_1_0_,
        User.USER_EMAIL as USER3_1_0_,
        User.USER_FIRSTNAME as USER4_1_0_,
        User.USER_LASTNAME as USER5_1_0_,
        User.USER_PASSWORD as USER6_1_0_,
        User.USER_COUNTRY_CODE as USER7_1_0_,
        User.USER_PHONE as USER8_1_0_,
        Address.ADDRESS_ID as ADDRESS1_0_1_,
        Address.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS2_0_1_,
        Address.ADDRESS_LINE2 as ADDRESS3_0_1_,
        Address.CITY as CITY0_1_,
        Address.COUNTRY as COUNTRY0_1_,
        Address.STATE as STATE0_1_  
    from
        T_USER_DETAILS2 US,
        T_ADDRESS_DETAILS AD 
    where
        US.ADDRESS_ID = AD.ADDRESS_ID 
        AND US.USER_FIRSTNAME = ?
```

I am getting this error:

Caught : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

i know this error comes when we miss some comma in select clause. but i can see everything is perfect in the select. Could any one assist me on this.

Comment: `User` is a reserved word and needs to be quoted: `"User".USER_ID` instead of `User.USER_ID`. But you don't have a table alias called `User` in your query. The alias is `US`. And you should be using explicit `JOIN`s instead of the implicit ones.

Comment: no that is not the problem as far as i know.. and about that alias name...i used the alias name US to join the tables ..since the two tables contains the columns with the same name so this can create ambiguity at the hibernate end(mapping). this is how we fetch mulitple entities in hibernate. check my .addEnity("User",User.class) that alias is coming from there

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when i removed `<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>` from the datasource bean. You can also change it to `SELECT 1 from DUAL`.